# Option for figure to appear just before the first reference in the text?

Tags: floats

Using some combination of the `[htpb!]` options (or some other means I'm not aware of), is it possible to allow a floating figure to be placed *immediately before* the first reference in the text, rather than on the following page?

Consider an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

    \section{Lorem ipsum}
    \lipsum[1-2]

    \section{Results}

    \lipsum[3]

    Results are shown in \cref{fig:results}.

    \begin{figure}[hbt]
        \includegraphics{Figures/results}
        \caption{Some results}
        \label{fig:results}
    \end{figure}

    \lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

For my "results" figure (a pdf, roughly 5cm square), this code will place it at the top of the following page. In this case, I would prefer that the figure be on the same page, just above the first reference in the text if necessary.

Is there combination of `[htpb!]` that will use this order of preference for placing the float?

1. Here
2. At the bottom of this page
3. **Just before "Here"**
4. At the top of the next page

Number 3 seems to be the option that is missing. From my understanding of float behavior, LaTeX will always place the float between text paragraphs, meaning there should be space between `\lipsum[3]` and the paragraph where I've referenced the figure. *That* space is the "just before" where I would like LaTeX to *automatically* place the figure when the next option would be the following page.

**Without invoking the figure before the reference in the text**, is there a way to have the figure appear before the text where it is invoked?

Here's what I want it to look like:

[image]

I accomplished this by moving the figure above the reference. I want to LaTeX to do that for me, but not all the time -- only when the next best option is the top of the next page.

Comment: Well, the `[t]` option will place it on the same page as the reference is made.  Else, one could manually invoke the figure with `[ht]` option as its own paragraph, *prior* to the `\cref`.

Comment: So you would specify two locations in the text, the second being the preferred location and the first being the alternate.

Comment: the posted code should always demonstrate the problem, a fragment that can no t be run is not so useful. the `t` option means exactly what you ask for (unless you are using the `flafter` package.  (It's almost always best to include `p` as well)

Comment: Note the location of the `\cref` is not used at all what is used is the location of the `figure` environment. but you can put these at the same point.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes this will not place the figure before where it's invoked.

Comment: @JohnKormylo how?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle in this case, I'm afraid an MWE would just result in lots of people just showing me how to invoke the figure before the `\cref`. But your second point is insightful -- perhaps what I'm asking is impossible?

Comment: @LShaver no, see how everyone answering has had to construct a full test document, had you provided one that extra work would not be needed.

Comment: @LShaver it isn't clear what you mean in your comment to Steven, the `t` option does naturally allow it to appear before it is invoked as it can appear at the top of that page.

Comment: as an addendum to @DavidCarlisle's comment, the `t` option will allow a figure to appear at the top of the *current* page only if there is room for it taking into account all the text that has already been processed.  so if you always want a figure to appear *before* its callout, you should place the input *before* the callout.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I was unclear -- `[t]` will not place the figure _immediately_ before the reference. Also, I concede your point on MWE -- I've included one here.

Comment: @barbarabeeton that's precisely the point of my question -- I only want the figure before the callout if the alternative is the following page. Thus putting the input before the callout is not a solution. I've done this in editing, but of course it means going through and tweaking each figure, which is what I'd like to avoid.

Comment: oh if you need it immediately before then just put it before teh `\ref` and use `[H]` from the float package so it dpesn't float, but that means you should accept the other answer, or i'm confused:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried to clarify the question. Without invoking the figure in the space just before `\cref{figure}`, is there any way to have LaTeX put it there, rather than on the next page? Even if this moves the `\cref{figure}` to the next page?

Comment: latex is a one-way operation.  except for the situation where there is still enough space on a page *after* the calling text has been processed, there is no way to move a figure to the top of that page other than placing the input for the figure *before* the callout.

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding, the intended solution should try to prevent the figure from *floating*. The proposed solutions given below does exactly this.

The first solution does not make the figure float at all. It simply utilizes the `\captionof` command from the [`caption`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package.

The second solution forces the float at its current location by utilizing
the `H` placement option from the [`float`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/float) package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\section{First Method --- Use the \texttt{caption} Package}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{center}
  Actual Figure\\
  Actual Figure\\
  Actual Figure
  \captionof{figure}{Figure caption 1.}
  \label{fig:results1}
\end{center}



Results are shown in \cref{fig:results1}.


\section{Second Method --- Use the \texttt{float} Package}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}[H]
  \begin{center}
    Actual Figure\\
    Actual Figure\\
    Actual Figure
    \caption{Figure caption 2.}
    \label{fig:results2}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}


Results are shown in \cref{fig:results2}.



\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 because this is *the* answer; but if I can propose an improvement, I’d make two separate listings for the two solutions, so users can tell that the first requires only the `caption` package, and the second only the `float` package.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti I see nothing in the question that indicates that the figure shouldn't float?

Comment: Thanks, that was the way I wanted to go first, then I tried to see whether both the solutions can be put together.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I think that this request is implicit: [your answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/370233/69818) shows that, indeed, there’s nothing in the float placement algorithm of the LaTeX2e kernel that prevents floats from appearing above their first reference, *provided* that the figure and the reference both fit into the same page.  In your code, above, it suffices to add one more line to the “aaa” text and the figure will move to the next page.  The OP says that, in this case, (s)he would prefer the figure to go on the next page too.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti hmm that must be fixable: (page break between the migrated figure and the line it migrated from)

Comment: As @DavidCarlisle indicates, I _would_ prefer figures to float.

Answer (score 1):

The default figure positioning will place the figure at the top of the current page. In this example it is placed at the top even though the reference (and the figure source) are on the last line of the page.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

aaa\\aaaaaa\\aaaaaa\\aaaaaa\\aaaaaa\\aaaaaa\\aaaaaa\\aaaaaa\\aaa
aaa\\aaaaaa\\aaaaaa\\aaaaaa\\aaaaaa\\aaaaaa\\aaaaaa\\aaaaaa\\aaa

\section{Results}
Results are shown in \cref{fig:results}%
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \label{fig:results}
\end{figure}.

aaa\\aaaaaa\\aaaaaa\\aaaaaa\\aaaaaa\\aaaaaa\\aaaaaa\\aaaaaa\\aaa
aaa\\aaaaaa\\aaaaaa\\aaaaaa\\aaaaaa\\aaaaaa\\aaaaaa\\aaaaaa\\aaa

\end{document}
```

The reference is to section 1 not to the figure as there is no caption, a feature of the code in the question:-)

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses tikzpagenodes to determine how much space is left on the page.  It also uses the aux file to communicate between the two locations.  Consequently, it takes 3 runs to get a stable solution.

The idea is to place the `bifigure` environment where you want it to go if it won't fit at the desired location, `\bilocation`.  If it won't fit in either location, it will be moved to the top of the next page.

In this case, `26\baslineskip` or less will fit the desired location, `27\baselineskip` will fit the first location, and `33\baselineskip` will wind up on the next page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newcounter{binumber}
\newsavebox{\bipolar}
\newlength{\bidistance}
\newif\ifbipolar% okay to expand image at \bilocation

\newcommand{\newbilocation}[3]% #1 = bifigure counter, #2 = \thepage, #3 = \bidistance)
 {\expandafter\xdef\csname bipage#1\endcsname{#2}
  \expandafter\xdef\csname bidistance#1\endcsname{#3}}

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{bifigure}{% place at secondary (first) location
  \stepcounter{binumber}%
  \parindent=0pt
  \parskip=0pt
  \def\@captype{figure}%
  \global\setbox\bipolar=\vbox{\BODY}%
  \@ifundefined{bipage\thebinumber}% first time
   {\afterpage{\clearpage\usebox\bipolar\vskip\textfloatsep}}%
   {\expandafter\let\expandafter\bipage\csname bipage\thebinumber\endcsname\relax
    \ifnum\bipage=\value{page}%
      \expandafter\bidistance\csname bidistance\thebinumber\endcsname\relax
    \else
      \bidistance=0pt
    \fi
    \ifdim\bidistance<\dimexpr \ht\bipolar+\dp\bipolar+\textfloatsep\relax
      \tikz[remember picture]{\pgfextracty{\bidistance}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointorigin}%
          {\pgfpointanchor{current page text area}{south}}}%
        \global\bidistance=-\bidistance}%
      \ifdim\bidistance<\dimexpr \ht\bipolar+\dp\bipolar+\textfloatsep\relax
        \global\bipolartrue% let \bilocation handle it
      \else
        \vskip\textfloatsep
        \usebox\bipolar
        \vskip\textfloatsep
        \global\bipolarfalse
      \fi
    \else
      \global\bipolartrue
    \fi}%
}

\newcommand{\bilocation}% place at preferred (second) location
 {\tikz[remember picture]{\pgfextracty{\bidistance}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointorigin}%
      {\pgfpointanchor{current page text area}{south}}}%
    \global\bidistance=-\bidistance}%
  \ifbipolar
    \ifdim\bidistance<\dimexpr \ht\bipolar+\dp\bipolar+\textfloatsep\relax
      \afterpage{\clearpage\usebox\bipolar\vskip\textfloatsep}% next apge
    \else
      \vskip\textfloatsep
      \usebox\bipolar
      \vskip\textfloatsep
    \fi
  \else% account for existing image
    \advance\bidistance by \dimexpr \ht\bipolar+\dp\bipolar+2\textfloatsep\relax
  \fi
  \protected@write\@auxout{\let\arabic=\relax}%
    {\string\newbilocation{\thebinumber}{\arabic{page}}{\the\bidistance}}%
 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\rule{1pt}{33\baselineskip}

\begin{bifigure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=.2\textheight]{example-image}
    \caption{Needed for label}\label{fig:results}
\end{bifigure}

\section{Results}
Results are shown in \cref{fig:results}.

\bilocation

\lipsum[1-4]\clearpage
\end{document}
```